# python2.7 : iteratiing over list of dicts and evaluating the required value

Tags: python, json, api, parsing

Code :

```
import json
import urllib
URL = 'www.xyz.com'
data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url)
print data   
[[{"Region":"Europe", "Details":[{"gender":"male", "name":"john", "age":"24", "status":"Ok"}, {"gender":"female", "name":"Rebecca", "age":"22", "status":"None"}], "country":"Germany"}], [{"Region":"Asia", "Details":[{"gender":"male", "name":"kim", "age":"27", "status":"None"}, {"gender":"male", "name":"jen", "age":"22", "status":"None"}], "country":"China"}]]
# here is what I have tried
for i in data:
     for j in i:
          for key in j.keys():
               dicx = j[key]
               for k in dicx:
                 if isinstance(k, dict) and k['status']=='None':
                 print (i['region'], k['name'])) #I wnant to store this value in a variable rather than printing.
#this is giving me the following output.  

Europe, Rebecca
Asia, kim
Asia, jen
```

Scenario : From the data above I want to check if in all "Region"(key) if "status"(key) is "Ok"(value) or "None"(value), if the "status"(key) is "None"(value) then it should return me the details(value) of that particular "Region"(key) along with the "name"(key).

ex:- 
desired output (referenced from above data)

```
Europe, Rebecca

Asia, (kim, jen)
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to iterate over it using loop
but I am not getting the desired output.
I am getting a output similar to this :
Europe, Rebecca
Asia, Kim
Asia, Jen
I dont want the output to be repeated (As i have used loops to iterate so it is like this)
Also i am not able to store this values into a variable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: @jamesorc - please post the code that is *not working* to expectations as well as a description (like your comment)

Comment: Apologies for the incomplete part, updated the section above.

Comment: [made in javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/sge3mkLg/3/) you can look at the logic and convert to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty ugly, but may do want you're asking:

```
matches = []
for i in data:  #
                # no changes here
                if isinstance(k, dict) and k['status']=='None':
                    # print (i[0]['Region'], k['name'])
                    matches.append(([i[0]['Region'], k['name']]))
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in matches:
    res[k].append(v)

for k, v in res.iteritems():
    if len(v) == 1:
        print'{}, {}'.format(k, v[0])
    else:
        print '{}, ({})'.format(k, ', '.join(map(str, v)))
```

**Edit #1:**

```
...
for k, v in matches:
    result[k].append(v)

mystr = ''

for k, v in result.iteritems():
    if len(v) == 1:
        mystr += '{}, {}'.format(k, v[0])
    else:
        mystr += ' {}, ({})'.format(k, ', '.join(map(str, v)))

print type(mystr)
print mystr
```

output:

```
<type 'str'>
Europe, Rebecca Asia, (kim, jen)
```

An example with 3 regions:

```
<type 'str'>
Europe, Rebecca America, (David, Ricardo) Asia, (kim, jen)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But the code above does not fix the issue it just returns me all the (values) of key ("name") .
Also the problem statement requires to hold the output in a variable.

Comment: The above code returns you *all* the values key ("name") -> "john", "Rebecca", "kim", *and* "jen"? Using the `list` `data` from the question the above code (when I run the script using the data list), produces the stated desired output, namely "Rebecca", "kim", and "jen". Which names do you *not* want in the output? What type is the output to be stored in the variable, a `str`, `list`, `dict`, or is not important, just store it in a variable? The variable `res` is a `defaultdict(<type 'list'>)` which holds the output -> `{'Europe': ['Rebecca'], 'Asia': ['kim', 'jen']}`

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
After executing : `for k, v in res.iteritems(): if len(v) == 1: print'{}, {}'.format(k, v[0]) else: print '{}, ({})'.format(k, ', '.join(map(str, v)))' # the output which I gain#  ``Europe, Rebecca  Asia,  ('kim, jen)` should be stored in a variable (preferably string) the rationale behind this is I need to again filter in this output for few names _Ex_ `if  in 'jen' in output: # return Asia , kim`. Also a question here , In the above json data I have 2 region (list) what if I encounter with 3 or more region(list) ->> will this work out?

Comment: @jamesorc please see updated answer. I've tested the code with 3 regions and I've included that output for your review & consideration.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the help.@downshift